# Which manufacturers who make BadUSB possible on their drives?

Tags: usb-drive, firmware

So as we all know by know BadUSB is possible on Phison 2251-03 chips. But are there any more reflashable devices in the wild that could be dangerous? And if there are is the firmware easily changed or does it require OEM tools?
I'm asking about this because I have once, when broken my USB stick, stumbled upon a Chinese manufacturer flashing tools and although i couldn't understand how to actually do it I'd guess some people could actually make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a clear list of what products are vulnerable, as manufacturers will use different chips even in one batch of products. So you'll never know what chip you have until you open the product.

They did however try to map this:

> They found an unpredictable patchwork of results. All of the USB storage controllers from Taiwanese firm Phison that Nohl tested, for instance, were vulnerable to reprogramming. Chips from ASmedia weren’t, Nohl’s tests found. Controller chips from fellow Taiwanese company Genesys that used the USB 2 standard were immune, but ones that used the newer USB 3 standard were susceptible. In other categories of device like USB hubs, keyboards, webcams and mice, the results produced an even messier Excel spreadsheet of “vulnerable,” “secure,” and “inconclusive.”

This list can be found [here](https://opensource.srlabs.de/projects/badusb)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! BTW can the more extensive excel spreadsheet mentioned be found on the web?

Comment: I tried to find it, but no luck so far, plus the wiki seems to be pretty extensive too ;)

Comment: Alright I'll keep searching and in the meantime study the wiki :) Thanks a lot :)